# Facebook sdk 2.0 Login in my Android application when user Logged in outside my Application

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

Now I am Able to login to facebook and log out of it, but my problem is,, suppose user has logged in to facebook outside our application and again when he opens our application it will ask for login .

can i make user to directly login to facebook when he is logged in outside my application?? if yes can anyone guide me how to do that. currently iam testing in emulator. and my app is built in api 16. thanks for any Help

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as you have logged into any of the web application lets say **`gmail`** or **`quora`**,  then you must know that there is a session that is maintained for that user.

Similarly when you login into facebook on your mobile phone there is a session maintained and this isn't for a small time but facebook internally do it using its **sharedpreferences file** I guess.

Now to read those **sharedpreferences** file, Facebook has provided some helper methods using them you can determine if the user is logged into the official facebook app or not.

Also you have an activity in your application where you decide to ask user to login or redirect him to the next screen (knowing he is already logged in).

This is a method from Official SDk that lets you know about the session state of user,

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
```

If the value of session is not `null` then you may use, `sessionCallback` and decide if user is logged in or not.

Comment: Do You have any idea of doing this in facebook sdk 2.0??

Answer (score 0):

For Facebook SDK try to use SSO (Single sign off) in this  it will automatically check that a session is null or already maintained. If null then it will pop up for signin/login of not then it will simply redirect your desired page
to check session if you want to then you can use this

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
```

Comment: Do You have any idea of doing this in facebook sdk 2.0??

Comment: Try to update to sdk 3.x its much more easier than 2 and a bit more relaxing than 2.x SDK SSO is initiated in sdk 3.x